# JTextPane shows color different from browser of an HTML 

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I am loading a simple HTML page in `JTextPane` which is showing different color than when viewed in a browser, and also the div tag's height and width are changed.

the HTML file has 1 div tag only nd that is:

```
<div height ="200" width="100" style="background-color:#0F9">this the div tag  </div>
```

I am simply calling `setPage` for `JTextPane`.

This is how it is displayed in the JTextPane

[image: This is how it is displayed in the JTextPane]

This is how it should be dislplayed(it is from firefox)
[image: This is how it should be dislplayed(it is from firefox)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into the same problem. As documented here (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/CSS.html), you can use background-color. The value of it has to contain 7 characters, for example

`background-color:#00FF99;`

Comment: The color is fine now, but why the height and width are changed?

Comment: Your code shows height=200 and width=100, that's what your picture shows as well? I can't see a problem there - try to edit those values!

Answer (score 0):

I think thats because JTextpane doesnt support css.

Edit:
try something like this

```
<div height ="200" width="100" bgcolor="Silver">this the div tag  </div>
```

Comment: less reputation. cant comment.

Comment: Is there any workaround?(to get css support on any component)

Comment: you could try the DJ project (http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/). it has a full featured Browser. but you need to include native libraries for all the platforms u intend to support.

Comment: You can change color to #00ff99. Color shortcut #0f9 is not properly interpreted.