# Is it possible to color only a portion of JTextpane?

Tags: java, swing, background, jtextpane

Hi I am trying to find out whether it is possible to apply background color only to a portion of JTextpane? For example if I have a JTextpane of size 300 X 400 then can I apply some color to a portion 300 X 200 ?

I am not posting any code as I dont have any.

Eg: [image]

Comment: Are you trying to [highlight text](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5674128/230513)?

Comment: This is not a simple task. The problem is, text is painted as part of the call to paintComponent, which also paints the background.  What you would need to do is set the text pane as transparent (setOpaque(false)), override paintComponent, paint the background, paint your color and call super.paintComoponent last

Comment: Thanks will try that. I have posted the sample screenshot above

Comment: Can you use [HTML formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9615991/230513)?

Comment: @user1815809, you've post 13 questions and not accepted a single answer in any of those questions. I think I'll skip answering this one.

Comment: Hey camickr sorry If I haven't accepted any.. I am looking for some better solution. For now I am trying the one suggested by MadProgrammer.

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to add `StyleConstants.Background`, as a parameter to `addAttribute()` of the `StyleContext`, which will return one `AttributeSet` object. Hope this is what you looking for :

```
import java.awt.*;    
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.StyleContext;

public class TextPaneTest extends JFrame
{
    private JPanel topPanel;
    private JTextPane tPane;

    public TextPaneTest()
    {
        topPanel = new JPanel();        

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);            

        EmptyBorder eb = new EmptyBorder(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));

        tPane = new JTextPane();                
        tPane.setBorder(eb);
        //tPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY));
        tPane.setMargin(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));

        topPanel.add(tPane);

        appendToPane(tPane, "My Name is Too Good.\n", Color.RED, Color.WHITE);
        appendToPane(tPane, "I wish I could be ONE of THE BEST on ", Color.WHITE, Color.BLUE);
        appendToPane(tPane, "Stack", Color.DARK_GRAY, Color.BLACK);
        appendToPane(tPane, "Over", Color.MAGENTA, Color.BLUE);
        appendToPane(tPane, "flow", Color.ORANGE, Color.YELLOW);

        getContentPane().add(topPanel);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);   
    }

    private void appendToPane(JTextPane tp, String msg, Color f, Color b)
    {
        StyleContext sc = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext();
        AttributeSet aset = sc.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY, StyleConstants.Foreground, f);
        aset = sc.addAttribute(aset, StyleConstants.Background, b);

        aset = sc.addAttribute(aset, StyleConstants.FontFamily, "Lucida Console");
        aset = sc.addAttribute(aset, StyleConstants.Alignment, StyleConstants.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);

        int len = tp.getDocument().getLength();
        tp.setCaretPosition(len);
        tp.setCharacterAttributes(aset, false);
        tp.replaceSelection(msg);
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    new TextPaneTest();
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Here is the output :

[image: TEXTPANE]

Comment: Hi Gagandeep, Thanks for the reply. But I am not looking for this. I believe the above example is only highlighting text but not coloring the entire panel from left end to right end. I am looking for something like the screenshot given in my question